# Create view must be the first statement in the batch

Tags: sql, .net, view

I'm running a **set of script files** from a .NET based windows application. One of the files has the following script -

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYS.VIEWS WHERE NAME = 'TP_LEAVEDATA') EXEC SP_RENAME 'TP_LEAVEDATA', 'TP_LEAVEDATA_BKP_EXPORT_TEST1' 
CREATE VIEW TP_LEAVEDATA AS
SELECT USERNAME, Dept, LeaveType, LeaveFrom, LeaveUpto FROM LeaveRequest_DATA
```

When I execute the script I get an error **create view must be the first statement in the batch**

I can not use **GO** keyword here because I'm running the scripts through my application, I can not use **execute sp_executesql** because there are similar files for creating stored procedures as well (which contain single inverted commas inside the query itself). What are the options that i have now ??

PS: The issue doesn't occur with create table command though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use put GO before it:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYS.VIEWS WHERE NAME = 'TP_LEAVEDATA') BEGIN
    EXEC SP_RENAME 'TP_LEAVEDATA', 'TP_LEAVEDATA_BKP_EXPORT_TEST1' ;
END;
GO

CREATE VIEW TP_LEAVEDATA AS
    SELECT USERNAME, Dept, LeaveType, LeaveFrom, LeaveUpto
    FROM LeaveRequest_DATA;
```

Another option is to use dynamic SQL for the view creation.

Comment: And don't forget that, if needed, you may have to grant Permissions to your new View. Especially if your application access your SQL through a dedicated user.

Comment: I'm still getting the error - "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch."

Comment: I think 'GO' is understood only by SQL Server clients to divide the queries into batches.